# Preview a small picture when pasting Url/link into textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, url, hyperlink

I want to make somethink like facebook, when people paste links into textbox, under the textbox a little image shows up which view how video could look like. how do they do it? Are there any jquery plugins or anything? i couldnt find anything about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the `jQuery Preview`

jQuery Preview is a plugin that allows users to preview URLs before submitting them to be saved by an application. Facebook, Google+ and Yammer are all examples of tools with this functionality.

Here's the [**Demo**](http://embedly.github.io/jquery-preview/demo/) page.

Everything from the basic setup, how it works to options, events is explained here.

Comment: perfect! exsactly what i needed :D